# Does callback get called when extrinsic is in block/finalized when the transaction is retracted?

Tags: polkadot-js

In some cases the transaction I am signing and sending gets retracted, but its my impression that they are usually included in a future block.

When using polkadot js with the promise api, if the transaction .isRetracted, will the callback still fire when its in block and/or finalized?

In this example, will the user be notified of finalized block in case of retracted?

```
tx.signAndSend(address, { signer }, (result: ISubmittableResult) => {
  if (result.status.isRetracted) {
    notify("retracted, taking longer than usual.")     
  }
  if (result.status.isInBlock) {
    notify("included")     
  }
  if (result.status.isFinalized) {
    notify("finalized")     
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it should still fire for both `InBlock` and `Finalized`, as the extrinsic can and should be again included into another block, which than gets finalized.

The extrinsic is still valid, but was part of a block which not get finalized, therefore got into the `Retracted` state.

This accepted answer also states this behavior:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/8873/3983