# When is a transaction `retracted`?

Tags: polkadot-js

PolkadotJS offers a status indication for a transaction receipt that is called `isRetracted`.
What does it mean and when does it occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A transaction can be in different [states](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5ee019610b9a163f10d97a8b04645db0a8b892ca/client/transaction-pool/api/src/lib.rs#L107-L133). The `retracted` state means that the transaction was included into a block `X`. This block `X` was seen as best block of the chain. At some later point there was another block `Y` imported as best block and this block `Y` is a fork of block `X`. So, the transaction pool sends the `retracted` event for all the transactions included in block `X` as they are not part of the best chain anymore. However, some of them are probably included in block `Y` and thus the transaction pool will send directly the `included` event for these transactions.

TLDR: A transaction was included in the best chain and then there was a re-org to another chain that may doesn't include the transaction yet.

Comment: Okay thanks. So this can be ignored as long as I listen for `finalized`?

Comment: Yes. I mean the transaction could still go to invalid state etc, but yeah in general nothing to worry about.